Where can I find the build number for every version of JetBrains released in the past?
I'm trying to figure out why my PyCharm / JetBrains Gateway setup has a bug that the support people are telling me is fixed in the latest version, and when I do ps aux | grep "pycharm" on the remote server I see a particular build number that doesn't match the latest build number on JetBrains' "Other Versions" page, but I still want to confirm that it's a previous build and not me misinterpreting the output of ps aux.



I eventually figured it out: when you go to the Other Versions page, you can click a dropdown next to each major version to choose one of its minor versions, and when you do that the Build number will change to the latest build number for that minor version.
So, in this example, you can see that the first two sections of the build number match what I was seeing in my terminal output (241.14494).

